# Can we perform CRUD with phpmyadmin using java

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

I just wanted to know, whether can we perform CRUD operations with PHPMYADMIN just like we perform with MySQL or PostgreSQL using java.

Comment: You actually want to know if there is an equivalent of phpmyadmin made in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is an web application from which you can send CRUD commands to the MySQL server, but this is not Java-related.